# How do I move a local git repo from parent folder to subfolder?

Tags: git, move, bitbucket, repository

I recently set up a git repo and I want to change its local directory.

Its current directory is:

```
Users/...Documents/Git
```

I want to change this so that there are several repos within this folder:

```
Users/...Documents/Git/project1
Users/...Documents/Git/project2
etc.
```

I want to move everything that's currently inside the parent folder into `$project1`.

I have already set up separate repos on bit bucket and I tried to link the subfolder with the bitbucket repo. But I think I messed it up, and I think I may now have the same repo connected to two local folders. I'm not sure of how to check or correct this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just move the entire directory. Just make sure that every subdirectory gets moved too. Git doesn't care, it just needs the .git subdirectory.

Comment: This answer to the question: "How do I move X?" boils down to "You just move X!". Awful. How do I best move it? Drag and drop (or equivalent Ctrl+C Ctrl+V)? Or is there a git command? Or some other way?

Comment: @Joooeey drag and drop works fine. If you're worried about how this would work or want to test, it's instructive to set up a fake set of directories and test it out.